# Inplace replacement in a file through a perl script

Tags: perl, edit-in-place

I wanted to know how to replace a string in place using a perl script rathere than a command line.
I searched through web andI tried below things.

I have a file:

```
> cat temp
this is one
>
```

And i have a below script that i wrote:

```
> cat temp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak
use strict;
use warnings;
my @ARGV=('temp');
$^I = '.bak';
my %hash=("one"=>"1");
{
    while (<>) {
        s/(one)/$hash{$1}/g;
        print;
    }
}
exit;
```

But when i try to execute(`>perl temp.pl`) this it just hangs and the file is also not getting updated.
The version of perl i am using is 5.8.4
Also the command line thing(`perl -pi -e 's/one/1/g' temp`) works perfectly.
Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change global `@ARGV`, and with `my` you made lexical `@ARGV`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV=('temp');

$^I = '.bak';
my %hash=("one"=>"1");
while (<>) {
        s/(one)/$hash{$1}/g;
        print;
}
```