# Search and remove string using Perl script

Tags: string, perl, search, replace

How to search and remove

```
6 ./ABC/DEG/gmail/xyz.txt
39415 ./ABC/DEG/yahoo/xyz.mp3
```

goal is to search and remove "/ABC/DEG"

```
Perl script
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = 'file.txt';

local @ARGV = ($infile);
local $^I = '.bac';
while( <> ){
    s/ABC/DEG//;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998180/inplace-replacement-in-a-file-through-a-perl-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either escape the forward slashes, or use different delimiters: `s{}{}`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s{/ABC/DEG}{};
    print;
}

__DATA__
6 ./ABC/DEG/gmail/xyz.txt
39415 ./ABC/DEG/yahoo/xyz.mp3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this directly from your terminal:

```
perl -pi -e 's{ABC/DEG}{}g' <filename>
```

or if you still want a backup:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's{ABC/DEG}{}g' <filename>
```

Comment: thanks, but getting error "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: @Mihir my mistake, I thought you wanted to replace `ABC` with `DEG`. To replace `ABC/DEG` with nothing you can either 1) escape the forward slash in your replacement or 2) use a different delimiter.